# PhpMailer не хочет отправлять сообщения и на сервере ошибка 405 Not Allowed

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

В этом деле первый раз и без понятия, что я сделал и что со мной не так, всё с ютуба и форумов, так что надеюсь, что какой то разбирающийся в этом человек мне поможет

PhP :

```
 <?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;                     
    $mail->isSMTP();                                         
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                       
    $mail->Username   = 'неважно';                    
    $mail->Password   = 'неважно';                              
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';        
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                   

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('неважно');
    $mail->addAddress('неважно');    

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                             
    $mail->Subject = 'TEST';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

HTML code :

```
<form action="PhP mailer/PhPCode.php" method="POST" class="BackgroundOfForm">
            <p class="MainText">Ми вам зателефонуємо)</p>    
            <input name="NameOfUser" class="NameField" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="name" required />
            <label for="name" class="label-name">
                <span class="content-name">Як до вас звертатись?</span>
            </label>
            <input name="PhoneOfUser" class="QuestionField" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="name" required />
            <label for="QuestionField" class="label-question">
                <span class="content-question">З приводу якого питання ви цікавитесь?</span>
            </label>
            <input name="QuestionOfUser" class="phone" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="phone" required maxlength="13" />
            <label for="PhoneField" class="label-phone">
                <span class="content-phone">Ваш номер телефону</span>
            </label>
            <button type="submit" class="button">Відправити</button>
        </form>
```

есть вот такая вот папка с Mailer ( путь к ней : корневая папка проекта\PhP mailer):
[image: это папка с моим Mailer]

Кроме шрифтов и bootstrap подключен :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

и на сервере при таком коде мне выбивает ошибка :
[image: это ошибка на сервере]

Пользуюсь Github Pages вместе с Google Domains

Что я делаю не так ? может быть я что то забыл или же не дописал ?

Comment: Может быть мне стоит установить SLL\TLS сертификаты на сайт ? потому что HTTPS сертификат у меня уже есть ? Или это одни и те же сертификаты ? я уже запутался в край...

Comment: Проблема со стороны сервера. Github Pages на сколько знаю только для статики, а значит php на нем не будет работать

Comment: Так... я ничего с этим не поделаю? А! и ты знаешь какие то замены этому ? Дело в том, что я, как ты уже понял, хочу сделать отправку из формы себе на почту и может быть есть какие то другие способы усложнить мне жизнь ? 

Comment: И ты можешь мне пожалуйста объяснить как это " git hub pages только для статистики ? "

Comment: Может быть сервер не поддерживает tls Попробуйте `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';`

Comment: хэх... только что попробывал ssl - 25, 465, 587 портами и tls - 25, 465, 587 портами на локальном сервере , ничего не захотело работать тоже самое, вот чёрт !

Comment: А от куда ты взял php Mailer? Если где то слева, то может попробуй поставить чистый с гитхаба

Comment: Это и был с гит хаба

Comment: Ты разобрался с проблемой ???? Хотел бы узнать